# Show zero in line chart in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Please help me understand how can I see the zero values in a line chart in BI. The X axis type must be Categorical.
The raw data looks like this: [raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLWVc.png).
The chart looks like this: [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSggo.png).
I am counting the PBI raised per month by priority. The months with no PBI of a certain priority are not showing as "0".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not showing '0' values as the data is null. It is a quick fix if you are using a measure to count items just by adding a '+ 0'. I've assumed in this example your are counting the Problem ID.

```
Measure = COUNT('yourtable'[Problem Id]) + 0
```

In the example image the top chart is showing the date axis as categorical, and show items with no data, with just a basic count. The second visual is the same but with the '+ 0' added to it to fill in the blanks

[image: Image showing the measure differences]

Comment: Thanks Jon for your reply. I did the measure but the nothing changed. Check the screenshot here https://imgur.com/VpOY8Cj

Comment: In your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSggo.png you have a table, with no value for the 2019-11 for 'Low', does the new measure fill this in with a 0?

Comment: No it doesn't. No change in the graph if I use in value field the column Problem ID or the measure based on the Problem ID column.

Comment: Thanks @Jon for this answer. It is very slim and clean. Unfortunately the date (x-axis) filters do not work after applying this measure. Did you have the same experience? Do you maybe know a solution to this?